# How to move product.price.render.bundle.customization from bundle.summary to product.info.price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, magento2.2.6

Magento 2 bundle product has a set of simple products. If you click each simple product's checkbox, its bundle product's price is re-calculated and displayed in bundle.summary block.
I want to move it to product.info.price so that it is displayed at the top of product-info-main. If it is moved using layout xml, it is displayed at product.info.price block, but its calculation for changing checkboxes is not updated.

By debugging on browser, I found

```
priceBox.trigger('updatePrice', changes)
```

of _onBundleOptionChanged function in Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle.js can't call updatePrice function of Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js, so its price is not re-calculated on checkbox click event.
Could you help how should I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. My problem was related to the fact that the priceBox was not initialized, therefore priceBox.trigger('updatePrice') did not work.
Check your code in the Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml.
My code was like:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
], function($){
    var priceBoxes = $('.product-info-price [data-role=priceBox]');

    priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
        return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
    });

    priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
});
```

after correcting it to

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'priceBox'
], function($){
    var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
        dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getId()) ?>]',
        priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

    priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
        return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
    });

    priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
});
```

the update of the configuration price worked again.